# How to aovid flickering of richTextBox when the text is scrolling down fast?

Tags: c#

I have a richTextBox wich i update append text to it all the time in a recrusive function.
In this case im adding directories from my hard disk to the richTextBox.
I did that when the text get down the bar on the right will stay down so if i want to see older text i need to scroll up.

Thep roblem is that when im adding directories as strings from the hard disk its working very fast and make the text and the bar on the right to flicker or jump.

This is the settings i did in the constructor:

```
richTextBox1.TabStop = false;
richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
richTextBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
richTextBox1.Enter += richTextBox1_Enter;
richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
```

This is the ruchTextBox text changed event:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

This make the richTextBox to scorll down so i all the time see the new text feeding if i want to see the earlier added text i need to grab the bar on the right up.

This is how im adding the text to the richTextBox in the recrusive function:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ColorText.Texts(richTextBox1, "Level: " + levels.ToString(), Color.Green); }));
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ColorText.Texts(richTextBox1, "   Loading The Url:   ", Color.Red); }));
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ColorText.Texts(richTextBox1, url + "...", Color.Blue); }));
```

This is the function im using to read the directories from the hard disk and return it as a List

```
private List<string> offline(string targetDirectory)
        {
            if (targetDirectory.StartsWith("http://"))
            {
                targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Substring("http://".Length);
            }
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory,"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                {
                    string t = "http://" + dirs[i];
                    directories.Add(t);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }


            return directories;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

could possible disable drawing on the form while you update it.

There is a message you can send called WM_SETREDRAW to disable and enable drawing.

http://fgaillard.com/2011/02/the-unfortunate-effect-of-wm_setredraw/